# Why are some cookies/data changes (e.g. via Burp) persistent and some are not?

Tags: javascript, cookies, burp-suite

I am not a developer, so please forgive my ignorance. Can someone explain why some cookies can be manipulated and submitted via Burpsuite proxy and some cannot? Is there something in JS (or whatever language) that checks against tampering? If so, can this be defeated?

Example: if I'm using Burpsuite during a penetration test, I can change the cookie value from `NotAnAdmin` to `Admin`. Sometimes this will work, and sometimes the server will still respond as if I did not make any changes and use the cookie as if it still said `NotAnAdmin`.

I have tried this with hashes as well, where I will try to swap out a hash or token or something to another one, but the site responds with the original token it generated or changes it back somehow and does not use the one I put in manually.

Comment: The fact that you're changing a cookie in the HTTP request doesn't make your browser aware that the cookie value changed and it will send the old value again in the next request.

Comment: That makes sense... but I still don't understand why sometimes it would work and sometimes it would not? What's that based on?

Comment: I guess it's hard to say without a concrete example. Sometimes the server may reflect the changed cookie back in a `Set-Cookie` header so your browser picks it up, sometimes it may not.

Comment: If you could elaborate a little and post as answer I'd accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this answer from stack exchange regarding why some cookies can be altered and some cannot.

Some are "signed" cookies. They use a hash and other information to prevent tampering.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897965/what-are-signed-cookies-in-connect-expressjs#11898142